# Query all accounts that is related to another account effeciently

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, loop

I've created a `custom lookup field for account` object and I call it as `primary_account__c`. Now, I want to query all `primary_account__c` with its related account what is the best way to do it ? I've tried the below code.

```
for(Account acc : [Select Id,Name from Account]) {
  total = 0;
  for(Account acc2 :[SELECT Id,name,some_data__c FROM Account WHERE primary_account__c =:acc.Id]) {
    total = total + some_data__c;
  }
  System.debug('The total' + total);
}
```

But because there are lots of data, I've encountered an error saying

`Too many SOQL queries: 201`

What is the best way to create the soql that will avoid this kind of error ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL includes [aggregate functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)  to help with problems such as this (where the problem is described in your comment to Himanshu's answer):

```
Map<Id, Decimal> m = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
for (AggregateResult ar : [
        select primary_account__c a, SUM(some_data__c) total
        from Account
        where primary_account__c != null
        group by primary_account__c
        ]) {
    m.put((Id) ar.get('a'), (Decimal) ar.get('total'));
}
// Use the map
```

Note that this will break when the number of Accounts that have a `primary_account__c` is large because of [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). If that happens, you will need to move the processing into a [Batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm) that implements `Database.Stateful` to operate on a batch of Accounts at a time and append to the results kept in a map.

Comment: What do you think is the possible number of accounts that will hit the governor limit ?

Comment: @Hope You are safe under 50,000. Over 50,000 may work - the governor limit enforcement seems less predictable for aggregate queries.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce allow only 100 SOQL per transaction and if we cross that limit we see Too many SOQL queries exception that is why as best practice we never put SOQL inside for loop.

Please find below solution where I am putting SOQL outside the for loop.

```
set<id> setAcc = new set<id>();
for(Account acc : [select id from account])
{
    //collect all the ids which can be used in actual logic
    setAcc.add(acc.id);
}

for(Account acc : [select id from account where primary_account__c in : setAcc])
{
    //Write your logic here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I have a total variable in my sample code to get the summation of certain field of all account which has same same primary_account__c . The problem I have, is that how will I Identify all account that has the same primary_account__c it seems like I am missing something. If you wouldn't mind can you please give me a sample code in order to group the account base on its primary_account__c ? thank you.